# Cannot change any icon sizes in Kubuntu System Settings...can someone help me please?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, icons, kde, system-settings

I'm a newbie when it comes to Ubuntu and I'm using the latest version of Kubuntu.

When I go to System Settings, then Application Appearance, then Icons, then Advanced, all the Size drop-down boxes for all the "Use of Icon" options have no numbers in them and do nothing when clicked. This happens every time, and regardless of what Theme I use. Currently  I'm using Humanity. I recently installed a new theme, Oxyfaenza, then removed it, but I don't know if that has anything to do with the error.

I tried reinstalling System Settings using apt-get, no dice. Does anyone have any suggestions to help me diagnose the problem and fix it? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...
I installed the "plasma-active-settings" package and the problem is solved.